# Comma gem export failing on Heroku - working on local environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, heroku, model-associations

Using the [the comma gem](https://github.com/crafterm/comma) and exporting CSV files perfectly fine on my local environment.  Also working on our staging environment which is running on an AWS instance.

ONLY failing on Heroku.

Heroku says:

```
2013-08-21T21:55:34.875724+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass):
2013-08-21T21:55:34.875724+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/job.rb:220:in `block in <class:Job>'
2013-08-21T21:55:34.875724+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in index'
2013-08-21T21:55:34.875724+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:18:in `index'
```

And line 220 in my Job model is:

```
Comma do
...
    customer :first_name
...
end
```

job.rb includes the line:

```
  belongs_to :customer
```

And customer.rb has:

```
  has_many :jobs
```

And as I mentioned this entire thing works great on my local box - I click the export button and out pops all the jobs, with each customer in the appropriate column.

For whatever reason it's only failing on Heroku.

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0-p0 on Heroku, Comma gem only *verified* up to 1.9.2 according to the documentation - BUT - I'm using Ruby 2.0.0-p0 on the staging server AND on my local environment and, again, it's *working*.

It's the 'klass" that's really throwing me off, because I don't have that anywhere in my code.  I've read other threads about the same error and their solutions, but I don't have things like nested model forms and the like.

It is some issue with Heroku & Ruby 2.0 and associations?  I've got the has_many and belongs_to on both sides, but still seems to be misunderstanding the association...

***UPDATE***

From the framework trace:

```
comma (3.1.0) lib/comma/extractors.rb:72:in `get_association_class'  <====
comma (3.1.0) lib/comma/extractors.rb:55:in `block in method_missing'
comma (3.1.0) lib/comma/extractors.rb:48:in `each'
comma (3.1.0) lib/comma/extractors.rb:48:in `method_missing'
comma (3.1.0) lib/comma/extractors.rb:15:in `instance_eval'
comma (3.1.0) lib/comma/extractors.rb:15:in `results'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was a legitimate bug in Comma gem - https://github.com/comma-csv/comma/releases

I reported and they accepted, fixed, and released v 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Your code may be the same on both local and prod, and it looks like you're using the same Rails/Ruby versions on local and production (good stuff!), but maybe your data isn't.  Perhaps what's wrong is that in production you're retrieving a Job and navigating to some association, but that association doesn't exist, you're getting a nil, and kaboom?

Comment: A very smart observation, but in this case it can't be true to my knowledge.  I use Mongo and every morning on local I perform a db.dropDatabase() and then db.copyDatabase() from my MongoLab instance which is what's driving the Heroku environment.  So I'm pretty sure it's exactly the same.  By pretty sure I guess one more troubleshooting step would be to export from MongoLab and import local in case the copy command does something differently and it really is inaccurate.

Comment: How about putting some debug statements in?  At the very least, dump the job ID / job.customer to stdout and hence to logs - I'm still betting it's nil :-)